Calculating aerodynamic forces on a random object
I've set out to designing a game that would let the user design a vehicle/plane and then fly it around and I'm interested in what would be the best way to go about the physics aspect of it.
The 3d game would let the user define the shape of the craft using points, and my question is how to best calculate forces and behaviour on the craft in terms of aerodynamics.
I've thought of a few different approaches to doing this.
One of them is to calculate a deflection force for each triangle / rectange on the model based on the air's velocity(speed), density(altitude) and turn the resulting force into lift and drag using trigonometry.
That I know is quite an unrealistic approach and puts forward a flaw in the logic because the air travels around the object and not through it.
But then I thought of a similar approach using deflections... demonstrated with a drawing here:

So basically add the deflected air velocity vector of the previous surface with air velocity vector and then look at the force required to allign it with the current surface and then split that into drag and lift, this approach would also let me introduce stalls via limiting the maximum negative angle of deflection for the next surface, but in all honesty I haven't gotten to calculating stall requirements yet(if ever).
And so my question really is, is this approach worth pursuing or is there another which would be more suitable.
The focus of the game is realism.

Even  the best physicists in the design  of  airplane  have difficulty calculating what you want for arbitrary shapes. So I think you have to change your idees completely.

Aerodynamic numerical simulations are very expensive, too expensive to run in real time.
A possible approach
If it's good enough, I'd suggest to use a flight dynamics approach, equation of motion of a rigid body with linear(ized) aerodynamic forces and moments written as
$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{1}{2} \rho |\mathbf{v}|^2 S \mathbf{c}_F(Re, Ma, \alpha, \beta)$$
$$\mathbf{M} = \frac{1}{2} \rho |\mathbf{v}|^2 S c \mathbf{c}_M(Re, Ma, \alpha, \beta) \ ,$$
with $\rho$ the air density (you can use a $\rho (z)$ function to take into account the density profile with altitude), $\mathbf{v}$ the velocity of the air (assumed to be larger than any gust), $S$ a reference surface (usually the wing surface of an airplane), $c$ the average wing chord, and $\mathbf{c}_F$, $\mathbf{c}_M$ the aerodynamic coefficients.
This coefficients can only depends on non-dimensional quantities, like:

Reynolds and Mach numbers $Re= \frac{\rho |\mathbf{v}| c}{\mu}$, $Ma = \frac{|\mathbf{v}|}{c}$, with $c$ the speed of sound (that you can evaluate as a function of altitude, knowing the standard atmosphere profiles for temperature, pressure and density);
angle of attach $\alpha$ and sideslip $\beta$ angles
the shape (not the dimension, already considered in $S$, $c$ and in the non-dimensional numbers) of the aircraft.

This is where you need to do some work to avoid expensive numerical simulations: you need to translate the shape of the aircraft to the aerodynamic coefficients.
